# How to add a jQuery Mobile "pageinit" bind function in Drupal?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add some mobile functionality to my Drupal site and need to bind some events in a "pageinit" function, NOT in a document ready, as the documentation says. Something like:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(event){

// bind events

});
```

How do I do that in Drupal? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well how would you do it if your site _wasn't_ Drupal? The answer is the same; javascript in Drupal is no different from javascript under any other system. If you need to know how to add custom Javascript to a page, please search the site as that question has been answered many times.

Comment: I would add something like what I posted in my message but I'm pretty sure Drupal 7 won't like that since the common use of document ready is something like:

`code` (function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.something_here = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
    ....

Comment: Ah ok...closures (that wrapper you're talking about) have nothing to do with Drupal (or jQuery for that matter). You can enable the `$` variable in exactly the same way: `(function($) { $(document).bind('pageinit', function(event){ ... }); })(jQuery);`. If you don't need Drupal behaviours there's no reason to use them

Comment: Right. That make sense. Will try that. Thank you very much! :)